# How to detach module event handlers in Marionette.js?

Tags: backbone.js, google-chrome-extension, marionette

I am making a Chrome extension using Marionette. The app is defined and running in the background page. Popup page adds Popup module

```
var App = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().App;
App.module("Popup", function (Popup) {
  ...
  Popup.on("start", function () { console.log(window); });
}
```

The module is started once the page is loaded and is stopped once the page is unloaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  App.module("Popup").start();
});

window.addEventListener("unload", function () {
  App.module("Popup").stop();
});
```

The problem is the module is attached to the app in the background page so every time after the first one the popup is opened this module definition is invoked and attaches new `start` event handlers to the already existing module. Obviously, all of the handlers are invoked when the module starts. And obviously, I could call the module definition only for the first popup opening. But a `start` handler is tied to the current `window`, so `console.log(window)` prints `null` for the `start` handlers attached in the previous popup openings and I'd like to detach those handlers.

PS. If it's of any importance, the actual problem is happening in

```
Popup.on("start", function () { Backbone.history.start(); });
```

namely in Backbone.history.getHash()

```
var match = (window || this).location.href.match(/#(.*)$/);
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Comment: Why is your UI logic executing in the background page? Why can't you move it to popup.js, where it belongs?

Comment: @RobW it isn't, or at least I don't think so. Background page takes care of data storages, sync, and such and it keeps the application. `popup.js` defines Popup module and its sub-modules which take care of UI. Is it better to have a separate application in the popup page rather than a module of extension-wide application?

Comment: In similar scenarios (where the background is used as a temporary storage spot and the popup as the front-end with the UI), I've written an abstraction that uses the background page solely for storing simple information. Then the UI logic can completely stay in the UI.

Comment: @RobW thank you, I'll try to make it work with separate popup application then.